# passing argument 2 of 'send' from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, sockets

I want to send a text file to my server, but I get this error:

```
warning: passing argument 2 of 'send' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   22 | send(sock, Download , 4096, 0);
      |            ^~~~~~~~
      |            |
      |            FILE * {aka struct _iobuf *}
```

My code on this part is:

```c
int sock;
FILE *Download;

void Downloads(){
    char *filename = "X.txt";
    Download = fopen(filename, "r");
    send(sock, Download , 4096, 0);
}
```

How can I fix it? It will run on **Windows**.

Comment: Do you know what `send` wants as arguments? And do you know what `fopen` returns?

Comment: What's the expected argument to `send` then? Btw, this is a C question, not a networking question. It also might matter which compiler you're using, and which `send` is this (POSIX like or something else?)

Comment: Note that Windows has a [`TransmitFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mswsock/nf-mswsock-transmitfile) function available.  You open a `HANDLE` to a file using `CreateFile()`, and then Windows can send the file bytes to an open `SOCKET` for you.

Answer (score 2):

`send()` sends an array of bytes that are already in-memory; it does not know how to read bytes out of a `FILE*` pointer.  To do what you want, you need to setup a loop that reads an array of bytes from the file, then calls `send()` to send that array to the network, then repeats until all the bytes in the file have been sent.  Be sure to always check the return value returned by each `send()` call since it might not always send all of the bytes you asked it to.